# AutoHotKey's %0% (number of command line arguments) produces inconsitent results

Tags: command-line, autohotkey

In AutoHotKey the way to see how many command line arguments are provided is %0%. This works well sometimes, however in the example below when it is part of a string concatenation  it doesn't return the number of arguments. Instead it returns the last argument's value.

```
MsgBox %0%    ; here is does show the number of arguments
MsgBox %1%    ; and the contents of the first one...
MsgBox %2%    ; second one...
MsgBox %3%    ; third one...


STRING := %0%
MsgBox %STRING% ; this should be the number of
              ; arguments but instead it is
              ; the last argument
exit
```

Comment: Don't use percent-signs when using the `:=` operator. Try `STRING = %0%`.

Comment: What is the proper way to use := with variables then?

Comment: `myVar := myOtherVar` would be correct. Using `myVar := %myOtherVar%` would be the same as typing `myVar := VALUE_OF_MY_OTHER_VAR`. You're basically calling a variable dynamically. But I'm not sure if command line arguments adhere to that rule. You should read the docs [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Variables.htm#Variables), they do a great job explaining all the quirks and rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply change the line `STRING := %0%` to `STRING = %0%`, you will get the desired result.